# Java EE 6 embedded glassfish embedded derby EJB unit test

Tags: jndi, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, derby, glassfish-embedded

questing is about javaee6 with embedded glassfish and embedded derby jndi lookup for data source at the time of deployment before unit test is executed....

Please find the persistence.xml here...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="mymodulePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:C:/myappDB;create=true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.file" value="./target/eclipselink.logs" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Please find the server console log here when the unit test is executed....

```
Jan 24, 2011 5:12:44 PM com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator createResource
WARNING: poolmgr.create_resource_error
Jan 24, 2011 5:12:44 PM com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl internalGetConnection
WARNING: poolmgr.get_connection_failure
Jan 24, 2011 5:12:44 PM com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource getConnection
WARNING: jdbc.exc_get_conn
Jan 24, 2011 5:12:44 PM org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/DD/WORKSPACES/lean-soa-arch/entities/target/classes/_mymodulePU.ejb
SEVERE: 
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.0.v20091127-r5931): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:309)
......
.......
......
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:126)
    ... 44 more
Jan 24, 2011 5:12:44 PM org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/DD/WORKSPACES/lean-soa-arch/entities/target/classes/_mymodulePU.properties
FINEST: End deploying Persistence Unit mymodulePU; session file:/C:/DD/WORKSPACES/lean-soa-arch/entities/target/classes/_mymodulePU; state Deployed; factoryCount 1
```

Answer (score 4):

@Bryan He's not trying to run Derby in network server mode, he wants to run it in embedded mode so I don't think your suggestion will help in that case.

The problem he is seeing is because he has a JTA datasource called jdbc/_*default defined in his persistence.xml. When embedded glassfish sees this it tries to look it up in its JNDI context and when it does it finds the jdbc/*_default resource which is defined in the domain.xml it is using. This by default is a network based Derby resource as defined in the domain.xml.

What Digambar needs to do is to start GF and create a new connection pool which uses embedded derby and create a new jdbc resource which uses that pool for the domain.

I used the glassfish web admin console but you can also use the asadmin command if you know all the command line switches for the various parameters. Either way your domain.xml will then have the new resources. Once you do that simply change your persistence.xml so that the jta-datasource references this new jdbc resource and you should be all set. You can also remove the two javax.persistence properties from your persistence.xml because they are not needed at this point (those settings set when you configure the new connection pool resource).

Make sure to set ;create=true to the ConnectionAttributes property when you configure your embedded connection pool.

After creating the connection pool and jdbc resources my domain.xml had the following. Yours may look slightly different based on the settings you need for your specific application.

```
<jdbc-connection-pool connection-validation-method="auto-commit" validation-table-name="SYS.SYSALIASES" allow-non-component-callers="true" connection-leak-reclaim="true" lazy-connection-association="true" connection-creation-retry-attempts="90" lazy-connection-enlistment="true" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="120" driver-classname="" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource40" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="60" description="" name="GFEmbeddedPool" is-connection-validation-required="true">

      <property name="DatabaseName" value="C:\tmp\db\unit-test"></property>
      <property name="ConnectionAttributes" value=";create=true"></property>
      <property name="AttributesAsPassword" value="false"></property>
      <property name="LoginTimeout" value="0"></property>

    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="GFEmbeddedPool" description="" jndi-name="jdbc/__embeddedGF"></jdbc-resource>
```

Answer (score 1):

The message "java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527" means that the Derby network server is not up and running. You need to start the Derby network server in order to connect to it. Here's how to start the server: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/adminguide/tadmincbdjhhfd.html

Comment: The OP talks about using embedded Derby. Embedded Derby does not run in network mode and you do not start the network server in this case.