# How do I connect to Derby which is included with WebLogic?

Tags: java, weblogic, derby, connectexception

I'm trying to add the Derby included with WebLogic as a data source.  I'm running WebLogic 10.3.5.  I didn't see a Derby flag in the setDomainEnv.cmd, so I added the client driver to the CLASSPATH:

```
set CLASSPATH=%PRE_CLASSPATH%;%WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH%;%POST_CLASSPATH%;%WLP_POST_CLASSPATH%;%WL_HOME%\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar
```

in setDomainEnv.cmd.  Now when I try to activate my data source in WebLogic I get:

```
An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for
details. Message icon - Error weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
Message icon - Error java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to
server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused:
connect.
```

What else do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Could be a firewall issue.

Comment: Some of the suggestions in this related question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781618/java-ee-6-embedded-glassfish-embedded-derby-ejb-unit-test/4783245?noredirect=1#comment28805446_4783245

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your local derby is not up yet. To check this, issue: 
`netstat -an | findstr 1527`.

See if it returns anything. If nothing is returned, try to start the Derby Network Service manually. Go to `<WLS_HOME>\common\derby\bin` and click the `startNetworkServer.cmd`.

Double check with `netstat` again. If it's there, you can try to add to the datasource.

Note: this only covers manually start the Derby network service (not automatially start it upon weblogic start, which a bit tricky).

Comment: You're right, the instructions I was following didn't say to start the server, but that was the essential missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

Either whatever is supposed to be running on that port isn't running or there is a firewall issue.